# Web scraping python <span class="b6a29bc0" aria-label="Beds">2</span>, <span class="b6a29bc0" aria-label="Baths">2</span>

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've to pull the text content on below html code for python web scraping, issue is with class parameter all the three variables having same class parameter so i tried with arial-label that is not working.

2,

3

**Property_beds = response.css('.b6a29bc0::text').extract()**

result
 getting both the variables"Beds","Baths", i want only single variable baths

'Property_beds': [2,3]

But i want to include aria-label="Baths" in response.css(), i tried using below code but the output list is empty

**Property_beds = response.css('span.b6a29bc0aria-label[attribute="Beds"]::text').extract()**

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add some code and example/snippet of html you are trying to parse.

Comment: ?  Property_beds = response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Beds]::text').extract()

Comment: this is the website i'm trying to web scrap [ https://www.bayut.com/to-rent/property/dubai/] were the data has same class

Comment: Hi Harr, Thanks for the answer that helped me to solve the issue, but the down the line, on some variables there is no **aria-label = beds** but having **aria-label= **Studio**, so i need to give multiple  aria-label's  like this **Property_baths = response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=[Beds,Studio]::text').extract()**  but this din't work. please let me know how to give multiple arial-labels.

Comment: i handled it correctly using Beautiful soup like below    **property_beds = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'b6a29bc0','aria-label':['Beds','Studio']})**   but when i tried using scrapy it is not working.

Comment: Hi harr,if the input is like **<span class="b6a29bc0" aria-label="Baths">1</span>'** 
     your code(**response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Beds]::text').extract()** is working fine but when the input is like **<span class="b6a29bc0" aria-label="Area"><span>4,155 '**  you code **Property_feet = response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Area]').getall()** is not working, this is because there is another **span** after the **aria-label="Area"** this cause the issue and not able to get the area to output field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single

```
Property_beds = response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Beds]::text').extract()
```

for multiple nodes use css Or syntax:

```
response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Beds], span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Studio]').getall()
```

Comment: thanks for the response the code is working as expected

Comment: Hi harr,if the input is like **<span class="b6a29bc0" aria-label="Baths">1</span>' **your code**(response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Beds]::text').extract()** is working fine but when the input is like **<span class="b6a29bc0" aria-label="Area"><span>4,155 '** you code **Property_feet = response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Area]').getall()** is not working, this is because there is another span after the aria-label="Area" this cause the issue and not able to get the area to output field

Comment: not sure I understand. Why not use first version in answer and change beds for Area?

Comment: The problem is with code, i need to read the **'<span class="b6a29bc0" aria-label="Area"><span>5,000 '** and get the 5000 to list, in this particular list span is opened two times but your code is reading it only one, is there any way to read the span after **aria-label="Area">** and get the value 5000 to list, i'm trying below code **Property_feet = response.css('span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Area]','span.b6a29bc0[aria-label=Area]').extract()** but not getting the value to list

Comment: Hi harr,   i'm having value like **<a href="/for-sale/property/abu-dhabi/page-3/" title="Next" class="b7880daf"><div title="Next" class="ea747e34 ">**  i need to pull out only ""Next" from title="Next" for the i used **soup.find('a',attrs={"title": "Next"}).get('title')** is there any method to get the tittle value with out using **.get("title")**

Comment: Hiya, might be easier to open a new question as busy with work at mo.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response sure i will do that